# How to add mobile responsive fixed dropdown menu

Tags: css, mobile, responsive

I'm trying to add a mobile responsive fixed dropdown menu. I tried this:

```html
<div class="row" style="position:fixed">
    <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Select Location
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#location1">Location 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#location2">Location 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#location3">Location 3</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#location1">ALL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any image or something to show us what the result should look like?

Answer (score 0):

its working fine right? may be you did't added bootstrap properly

jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

bootstrap javascript

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

bootstrap css

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

---

```css
.text {
    height: 3000px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="position:fixed">
         <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
         <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Select Location
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#location1">Location 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#location2">Location 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#location3">Location 3</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#location1">ALL</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
      
      
      <br><br>
    <div class="text"></div>
```

Comment: its working but I want it to be on the same position even when I'm scrolling.

Comment: @VishnuMR yes position also same, it working fine ?  or may be i did't understand the things properly ..